# “sudo shutdown now” in my crontab @reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, amazon-ec2

Now whenever my EC2 instance starts, it shuts down immediately, anyway to salvage this situation?

OS: Ubuntu18.04

Comment: *I hope this is not an April Fool’s joke.*

Comment: Where does the command and reference to crontab in your title come from? How do you know these are there? Or are you just assuming. I agree, sounds suspiciously like an April 1 issue.

Comment: @G-Man Why? Let's better hope _it is!_

Answer (score 3):

I've not tested this solution, but this is how I would go about it.

Since your instance persists data, I would guess there's a persistent volume associated with it.  You can use the console GUI or the CLI tools to get this volume ID.

Then I would create a temporary new EC2 instance and *attach* the existing volume as a second disk.  Once the second EC2 instance has booted you'll be able to `mount` the existing volume, edit the crontab entries, `umount`.

Finally, you can destroy the temporary EC2 instance.

And now your existing instance should be able to boot cleanly!